# Default text in UIAlertVIew on show

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

It appears that there are a number of questions asking this but nothing I have tried works for me. Simply, I would like an `UIAlertView` with `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` but with the input box preloaded with a given string when it is displayed - not as a placeholder, but as a default entry. Is this possible?

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"preloaded string"]];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

The example above uses setText which does not work. I have also tried:

```
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"text"];
```

just for interest, but this does not display even the placeholder so maybe I am missing something else.

Any pointers?

Comment: Try setting the `alertViewStyle` before?

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated since iOS8. You should move to  UIAlertController. In that case you can do stg like `UITextField *alertText1 = alertController.textFields.firstObject; [alertText1 setText@"Default Txt"];`

Comment: @Larme That works - thanks. Add as answer and I will choose it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIAlertController` instead:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
    // Configure UITextField here...
    textField.placeholder = "Placeholder"
}
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (_) -> Void in
    let textField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
    let value = textField.text ?? "Untitled"
    /// Save value here...
}
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(okAction)
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like

**AlertView**

```
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"sample" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Done", nil];

    [alert setAlertViewStyle: UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
    // Alert style customization

    [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];      
    [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setText:@"Richard"];        
    [[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"textvalue"];

    [alert show];
```

**UIAlertController**

```
 UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController

                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"sample"

                                message:@" "

                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];



    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)

     {


         [textField setText:@"Richard"];
         textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"textvalue", @"Login");


     }];
  [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
 // do your action on ok click

  }]];

    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {


    // do your action on cancel click
    }]];

    UIViewController *viewController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];

    if ( viewController.presentedViewController && !viewController.presentedViewController.isBeingDismissed ) {

        viewController = viewController.presentedViewController;

    }



    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:alert.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:viewController.view.frame.size.height*2.0f];

    [alert.view addConstraint:constraint];



    [viewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{



    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

you either need to create your own custom "popup" view that will look like `UIAlertview`like in [`here`](http://blog.typpz.com/2013/12/09/ios-sdk-create-a-pop-up-window/)  or use a open source implementation like [`SDCAlertView`](https://github.com/sberrevoets/SDCAlertView)

what you can also do is to use UIAlertController (as `UIAlertview` is also deprecated in IOS 8)

```
 UITextField *alert = alertController.textFields.firstObject;
 [alert setText@"YOUR ALERT TEXT HERE"];
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working 100%

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[[alert textFieldAtIndex:0] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"preloaded string"]];
[alert show];
```